# After reading .csv file in R all the data in one column... How can I separate?

Tags: r, csv, sorting, load

I do not always have to ask a question on stackoverflow but I simply cannot find any proper solution to my problem. I am trying to read a .csv file on R and everytime it opens, all the data appears in one column. I tried everything but I cannot separate the data. I would be happy about some help <3 This is the link of the data I am trying to get: https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/NY.GDP.PCAP.CD?end=2019&start=1990

I already tried to separate all the columns in Excel and tried several separate commands but I feel too stupid for this solution.

Comment: Which code do you use?

Comment: When I click the link, the downloadable file is a zip file and has 3 csvs in it. could you share an example or let me know which file youre looking at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you download the data programmatically via the World Bank API instead. You will need to install the package [WDI](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/WDI/index.html) for that.

```r
gdp <- WDI::WDI(
  indicator = "NY.GDP.PCAP.CD",
  start = 1990,
  end = 2019
)

utils::head(gdp)
#>                       country iso2c iso3c year NY.GDP.PCAP.CD
#> 1 Africa Eastern and Southern    ZH   AFE 2019       1512.271
#> 2 Africa Eastern and Southern    ZH   AFE 2018       1564.734
#> 3 Africa Eastern and Southern    ZH   AFE 2017       1628.587
#> 4 Africa Eastern and Southern    ZH   AFE 2016       1443.692
#> 5 Africa Eastern and Southern    ZH   AFE 2015       1538.552
#> 6 Africa Eastern and Southern    ZH   AFE 2014       1719.184
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are loading the main data file and not the two metadata files that accompany it. (Though these are worth reviewing to make sure you are interpreting the data correctly.)

If we look at the data in a text editor or in the RStudio "import dataset" wizard, we can see that the file has some metadata in the top few rows, but the bulk of the data starts in row 5.

```
"Data Source","World Development Indicators",

"Last Updated Date","2023-03-01",

"Country Name","Country Code","Indicator Name","Indicator Code","1960","1961","1962","1963","1964","1965","1966","1967","1968","1969","1970","1971","1972","1973","1974","1975","1976","1977","1978","1979","1980","1981","1982","1983","1984","1985","1986","1987","1988","1989","1990","1991","1992","1993","1994","1995","1996","1997","1998","1999","2000","2001","2002","2003","2004","2005","2006","2007","2008","2009","2010","2011","2012","2013","2014","2015","2016","2017","2018","2019","2020","2021",
"Aruba","ABW","GDP per capita (current US$)","NY.GDP.PCAP.CD","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","6283.00144344602","7567.25364168664","9274.51415613905","10767.3962204623","11638.7337057728","12850.2157123975","13657.6706444765","14970.1523419526","16675.2784883673","17140.4333687405","17375.2253063755","18713.4253880988","19742.3167386832","19833.8267458639","21023.1575127316","20913.2994971137","21377.0951851076","22050.8309318377","24104.6461765229","24975.6732567007","25833.445623022","27665.4264651752","29011.5592450359","25739.1372506975","24452.9283634427","26044.4359333351","25609.9557239373","26515.678080228","26942.3079764655","28421.3864931862","28451.2737445083","29326.7080582111","30220.5945232395","31650.7605367511","24487.8635601966","29342.1008575886",
```

Most CSV readers will by default use the first row for headers, but in this case the first row only has two labeled columns. To read the data with all the headers that start in row 5, we can skip the first 4 rows.

```
df <- readr::read_csv("~/API_NY.GDP.PCAP.CD_DS2_en_csv_v2_5182294.csv", 
    skip = 4)
```